# vlookup if range satisfies condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

here is what I want to do
I have two tables... the first column is the same in both tables and contains id.
the 2nd column in the 2nd table is the precision of the id (ex: -1, +3). the 2nd column in the first table is with the tolerances (ex -1+2, -5-2) ...so I want to search for all the values in 1st table that have the same ID as the selected row in the 2nd table and then if the precision is in the tolerance to get the value from the 3rd column in table 1.... in other word I want some sort of vlookup that vlookups only if the value of the precision is in the range.

Comment: I would do two Index/Match formulas, the first to compare, the 2nd to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic use of vlookup:

```
=IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$H$32,2,FALSE)<=B2,VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$H$32,3,FALSE)>=B2),VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$H$32,4,FALSE),"")
```

Then you just need to autofill that down your column:

[image: VLOOKUP Demonstration]

Good Luck.

(of course depending on how your data is organized by column - you could make an index/match version of this logic - like Doug said.)